# JDI: Error when I use WindowsManager.closeWindow()

Tags: java, jdi, jdiframework

I try to use WindowsManager.closeWindow() after test suite.
Window close, but then I have error.
My code:

```
@Test
public void monitoringMenuTest() {
    sidebar.select(Monitoring, Chart);
    chartPage.checkOpened();
    sidebar.select(Monitoring, Map);
    mapPage.checkOpened();
    sidebar.select(Monitoring, Railway);
    railwayPage.checkOpened();
}

@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)
public void teardown() {
    closeWindow();
    killAllSeleniumDrivers();
}
```

Stacktrace:

````
[null STEP 06:41.504] : Close current window
[ERROR 06:46.656] : >>> java.lang.Object@6e66636a
[ERROR 06:46.659] : Failed actions chain: WindowsManager.closeWindow() > WindowsManager.originalWindow()

[06:46.661] Failed to execute 'closeWindow' for element 'WindowsManager' during '5' seconds. invalid session idBuild info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-5', revision: 'b3a0d621cc'

org.mytests.tests.example.FmsMenuTests.teardown FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at Exceptions.java:25
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at Exceptions.java:25
            Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException at null:-1```
````